# % operator giving strange result in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, modulo, operations, arc4random

I am familiar with Mathematics and what the % operator (modulo) gives us for certain values.  However, I am following along a Swift code lecture, and the instructor wants to return a value somewhere between 0 and half of the height of the view.  He sets up the equation as:

var offSet = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.size.height / 2)

I must be missing something.  Wouldn't arc give a number between 0 and 1, and then performing % on the height (roughly 700 pixels) would always give 0.  Yet each time the code is run it offsets a random amount somewhere between 0 and half the height of the screen.  If I change % to * the program crashes.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the arc4random() man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html)

`"arc4random() function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1"`

So your random number will be something potentially large, then the modulo will bring it into the range of `0 - (height/2 - 1)`

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I misunderstood that random function.  I just ended up generating uniform random numbers from 0 to half the height.